# Xcode Flutter Plugin 'no such module'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, plugins

I'm trying to write a Flutter Plugin incorporating Snapchat's SDK, however, the plugin file keeps giving me the error 'no such module SCSDKCoreKit'

This is my pod spec in `plugin/ios`

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'snapkit'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'SnapSDK'
  s.platform = :ios, '12.0'
  s.preserve_paths = 'SCSDKCoreKit.framework', 'SCSDKLoginKit.framework', 'SCSDKBitmoji.framework', 'SCSDKCreativeKit.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework SCSDKCoreKit -framework SCSDKLoginKit -framework SCSDKBitmoji -framework SCSDKCreativeKit' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'SCSDKCoreKit.framework', 'SCSDKLoginKit.framework', 'SCSDKBitmoji.framework', 'SCSDKCreativeKit.framework'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

I then ran `pod install` in `plugin/example/ios` and embed the SDK in Xcode
[image: SDK Embed]

I can successfully import the SDK in `Runner/AppDelegate.swift` but get the error when trying to import it in `Development Pods/plugin/../../example/ios/.symlinks/plugins/plugin/ios/Classes/SwiftPlugin.swift`

I am quite new to Swift but any help would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the iOS build through Xcode, make sure that you've opened `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of `Runner.xcodeproj`. The pod information is in xcworkspace.

There's also an option to regenerate the Flutter iOS build. Delete the `/ios` folder in the Flutter project then run `flutter create --platforms=ios` to regenerate iOS project files. This should eliminate any misconfiguration previously done on the iOS build.